# Time out Error in send mail

Tags: c#, sendmail

I use this code to try and send an email. After a few seconds, it shows me an error message claiming the operation has timed out.  How can I resolve this issue?

```
try
{
    MailAddress from = new MailAddress("from@yahoo.com", "name", Encoding.UTF8);
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress("to@yahoo.com");
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
    message.Subject = "Test";
    message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    message.Body = "Test";
    message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
    client.Port = 465;
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("example@yahoo.com", "Password");
    client.Send(message);
    MessageBox.Show("sending Successfully!!!");
}
catch (SmtpException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you can reach `smtp.mail.yahoo.com` on port `465`? Sounds pretty much like a network related issue. Generally when something times out, it means that it tries to connect to the server for a certain amount of time and them stops and gives you an error.

One easy way to test this is to `telnet` to `smtp.mail.yahoo.com` on port `465` and see if it times out. You can use `Putty` or the built in `telnet`-client in windows, if you have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, your code won't work because yahoo.com does not provide you access via SMTP. For that you need to upgrade to **Yahoo! Mail Plus**.

Couldn't find any sort of kb from Yahoo! on this. I got the information from a Yahoo! article on [How to read Yahoo! Mail Plus using Outlook Express](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/classic/mailplus/pop/pop-08.html). The first two lines of the article are very relevant.

> Do you want to read and send your Yahoo! email with Outlook Express?
>   If you are a Yahoo! Mail Plus user you can.

And also, the outgoing SMTP server should be

```
client.Host = "plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem 
you have to set the clietn.port as 25 and you have to specify your login an password in client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login,password)

when i did that i can send mail without problem

there is the code

```
{
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("188.125.69.59");//you can put the ip adress or the dns of smtp server (smtp.mail.yahoo.com as exemple)
                // Specify the e-mail sender.
                // Create a mailing address that includes a UTF8 character
                // in the display name.
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress("from@yahoo.fr");
                // Set destinations for the e-mail message.
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress("to@gmail.com");
                // Specify the message content.
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
                message.Body = "This is a test e-mail message sent by an application. ";
                // Include some non-ASCII characters in body and subject.
                string someArrows = new string(new char[] {'\u2190', '\u2191', '\u2192', '\u2193'});
                message.Body ="cc";
                message.BodyEncoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                message.Subject = "test message 1";
                message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                string userState = "test message1";
                MessageBox.Show("sending"); 
                client.Port = 25;
               // client.Timeout = 40000;
                client.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("from@yahoo.fr", "pass");
                //client.SendAsync(message, userState);
                client.Send(message);
                MessageBox.Show("Sending message... press c to cancel mail. Press any other key to exit.");
                string answer = Console.ReadLine();
                // If the user canceled the send, and mail hasn't been sent yet,
                // then cancel the pending operation.
               // if (answer.StartsWith("c") && mailSent == false)
                //{
                  //  client.SendAsyncCancel();
                //}
                // Clean up.
                message.Dispose();
                MessageBox.Show("Goodbye.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following setting for domain `@yahoo.co.in`.

```
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        {
            smtp.Host ="smtp.mail.yahoo.co.in";
            smtp.Port = 25;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        }
```